# How can I use the pointy back button for my own buttons/navbar items?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

As I'm sure you know, navbars inside a navigation controller stack get a back button that shaped sort of like an arrow with a pointy end on the left. I want to use this button image for my own uibuttons and navbar items, but it's missing from from the attribute inspector > bar item > image drop down menu. Where is this graphic located and how can I use it?

here's a screen of the button to which I refer:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this programatically -

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button;
[button release];
```

You can use like below in xib-

[image]